# Is there an icon set containing icons for different platforms/stores (e.g. App Store, Play, Windows 8 Store, etc.)

Tags: icon

Is there an icon set containing icons for different platforms/stores (e.g. App Store, Play, Windows 8 Store, etc.)?

I am interested in grayscale icons similar to Glyphish and Glyphicons.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that some stores/platforms may disallow the use of third-party icons to represent them. I know [Apple does](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/AppStoreMarketingGuidelines.pdf).

Comment: Those stores supply "bagdges" to link to their store items, maybe that will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything about Win 8, but for Google and Apple you **have to** use their logos.

For **Android / Google**:

> We encourage you to use the Android and Google Play brands with your
>   Android app promotional materials. You can use the icons and other
>   assets on this page provided that you follow the guidelines described
>   below.
>   You may use the Google Play Store icon, **but you may not modify it**.
>
> As mentioned above, when referring to the Google Play Store app in
>   copy, use the full name: "Google Play Store." However, when labeling
>   the Google Play Store icon directly, it's OK to use "Play Store" alone
>   to accurately reflect the icon label as it appears on a device.

And the same applies to **Apple**:

> An App Store badge must be used in both marketing and advertising
>   communications, such as TV spots, print ads, video trailers, email,
>   newsletters, and websites, whenever you promote your app offered on
>   the App Store. Only the badges shown here are approved by Apple.
>   Badges must be used as provided and **cannot be modified**.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer, and not grayscale - but I found this [Google Play icon pack](http://silviu-eduard.deviantart.com/art/Google-Play-Icons-Pack-289358752) which you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free and decently customizeable solution I would recommend [Metro Studio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio).

While you do have to download software, it does allow you to customize icon size, colors, and backgrounds (you can remove background too and import the icons to Photoshop, or easily trace them and customize them in Illustrator).

I recently used this on a web project and I was very happy with the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I find this one useful and fully sufficient on many occasions. You get both PNG and PSD, so it's easier to customize them.

[http://gemicon.net/](http://gemicon.net)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! I'm not too familiar with what the OP is asking, so I'll ask you: Do the icons in the link relate to the icons in the different app stores mentioned? I almost upvoted for a link to a useful resource then checked myself when I wasn't sure if you had answered what the OP was asking.

Comment: I haven't checked thoroughly if icons contained in Gemicon package would be sufficient for all the purposes of an app store, yet many of them would, especially due to their resemblance to Glyphicons, therefore I thought OP might make use of them.

Comment: Unfortunately they only include the ones they show in the website (they rest are great, though!).

Comment: It's been awhile since I used them last time. My usage was limited to creating a small web app, and for that purpose they fitted perfectly. I'm afraid 600+ icons is a "marketing trick" unfortunately, as there are only ~210 icons, all of which you can see in the preview, yet in 3 different sizes, therefore making the number 600+.