# Looking for an elegant icon-set similar to Glyphish or Glyphicons, but colorful

Tags: icon

Does anybody know a decent and modern icon-set similar to Glyphicons that is colourful?

Comment: Why do I feel like something happened to this question?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing this with my other question [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/14007/is-there-an-icon-set-containing-icons-for-different-platforms-stores-e-g-app-s).

Answer (score 1):

If you already like the Glyphicons set I would be more inclined to purchase it and add my own colours with Photoshop.

Double clicking the layer will bring up the layer style menu. Add a color overlay -> select blend mode: overlay and then choose your colour!

If price is an issue, this is a very similar icon set free for personal and commercial use. http://salleedesign.com/resources/mimi-glyphs

Comment: I've already purchased it and a bunch of other decent bundles. I also do what you said every now and then, but I am looking for a "colorful" not "single-color" icon bundle. Something like [this](http://www.prekesh.com/Stock), but with more icons.